# JavaScript to Python, how to translate bitewiseAnd?

Tags: python, javascript, google-earth-engine

I'm using the Earth Engine API in a Jupyter notebook and I try to translate from JavaScript to Python a cloud masking function (the one given with the dataset)

```js
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};
```

I already fell in the trap of `and`, `or` and `not` that are protected in Python. I'm now facing an error with the `bitewiseAnd` keyword:

```py
def clouMask_landsat(image):
    """
    Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
    
    Args:
        image(ee.Image): image Input Landsat SR image
    Returns:
        (ee.Image): Cloudmasked Landsat image
    """
    qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
    
    # If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
    # or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
    cloud = qa.bitewiseAnd(1 << 5).And(qa.bitewiseAnd(1 << 7)).Or(qa.bitewiseAnd(1 << 3))
    
    # Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
    mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
    
    return image.updateMask(cloud.Not()).updateMask(mask2)
```

> AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'bitewiseAnd'

Is it simply a `&` or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo - `bitwiseAnd` not `bitewiseAnd`

Comment: I am very very ashamed but it's true .... work like a charm when corrected